# How to convert Chrome extension to firefox - url blocking/redirecting

Tags: google-chrome, firefox-addon

i have a problem, i made a chrome extension and opéra, but for Firefox, it's no working at all, my extension just block a list of urls i added to my background.js.
Can someone help me with the chrome conversion to firefox?

more details:
Im trying to convert my chrome extension to fireox, my chrome extension blocks a list of urls who are inside the background.js, im really stuck with firefox, i have tried to use the chrome version of my extension under firefox, it load the icon, the infos of the manifest.json, but the background.js dont work, the urls are not blocked

here i give you first my `manifest.json` code:

```
{
"name":"blocker",
"description":"block bad urls",
"version":"1.0",
"manifest_version":2,
"permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
       "<all_urls>" ,    
        "unlimitedStorage"
]      
,"icons":{"48":"icon.png"},
"background":{
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup":"popup.html",
    "default_icon":"icon.png"},
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["<all_urls>"],
"js": ["disablef12.js"]
}
]
}
```

and here its my `background.js`

```
var AUTHORIZED_DOMAINS= {
"www.url01.com": false,
"url01.com": false,
"www.url02.com": false,
 etc..
};
function extract_domain(url)    {
    var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
    return matches[1];
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) { 
var domain = extract_domain(details.url);
return { cancel: AUTHORIZED_DOMAINS[domain ]===false }; 
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},["blocking"]);
```

thanks a lot again for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

block urls:

full working example of how to block urls, bootstrap method:

https://github.com/Noitidart/PortableTester/tree/block-urls

download the xpi and drag it onto firefox, it blocks google and bbc.

```
const {classes: Cc, interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, results: Cr} = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');

var urls_block = [ //if urls ontain any of these elements they will be blocked or redirected, your choice based on code in observer line 17
 'www.google.com',
 'www.bbc.com'
];

var observers = {
    'http-on-modify-request': {
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            console.info('http-on-modify-request: aSubject = ' + aSubject + ' | aTopic = ' + aTopic + ' | aData = ' + aData);
            var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            var requestUrl = httpChannel.URI.spec;
            for (var i=0; i<urls_block.length; i++) {
             if (requestUrl.indexOf(urls_block[i]) > -1) {
              //httpChannel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED); //this aborts the load
              httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI('data:text,url_blocked', null, null)); //can redirect with this line, if dont want to redirect and just block, then uncomment this line and comment out line above (line 17)
             }
            }
        },
        reg: function () {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);
        },
        unreg: function () {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request');
        }
    }
};

function install() {}

function uninstall() {}

function startup() {
 for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].reg();
 }
}

function shutdown(aData, aReason) {
 if (aReason == APP_SHUTDOWN) return;

 for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].unreg();
 }
}
```

if you want an icon just add to the xpi file which is just a zip file renamed to xpi. add a file called icon.png

see this basic bootstrap template here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999